# Angular 4 component : call javascript/jquery code from another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

i have a jquery code which gets executed at `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
//myComponent.ts
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(function () {
    $('#myElement').click(function (e) {
        //code working fine here
    });
}
```

but i want to move it to an external `myScripts.js` to simplify the component

i tried moving tthe code to an external file then use `import` but this makes the script to be called only once so if i navigate to a child component (which erases the html element `myElement` with the `onclick` defined ) then back to the parent `myElement` is back without the onclick event

so **the question** is :

what is the best practice to use jquery/javascript with angular4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export your function from `myScripts.ts` and then `import` it and call it within `ngAfterViewInit()`.

After exporting correctly you should be able to do:

```
// app.ts
import { myInitFunc } from './myScripts';

ngAfterViewInit() {
  myInitFunc();
}

// myScripts.ts
export function myInitFunc(): void {
  $(function () {
    $('#myElement').click(function (e) {
      //do stuff
    });
  }
};
```

Take a look at `export`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export